# Difference between using Message Queue vs Plain Cron Jobs with PHP

Tags: php, message-queue, cron

We have a large web application built on PHP. This application allows scheduling tweets and wall posts and there are scheduled emails that go out from the server.

By 'scheduled', I mean that these are PHP scripts scheduled to run at particular time using `cron`. There are about 7 PHP files that do the above jobs.

I have been hearing about Message Queues. Can anyone explain if Message Queues are the best fit in this scenario? Do Message Queues execute PHP scripts? or do we need to configure this entirely differently? What are the advantages / disadvantages?

Comment: 22 Views. Anyone? Any answers?

Comment: I am also working on the same. What did you end up doing?

Comment: cron job ~ poor man’s message queue system. Depending on web host and intensity of the jobs, might work out just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using *Crontab* to make *asynchronous tasks* (asynchronous from your PHP code) is a basic approach where using a *job/task queue manager* is an elaborate one and give you more control, power and scalability/elasticity.

Crontab are very easy to deal with but does not offer a lot of functionalities. It is best for scheduled jobs rather than for asynchronous tasks.

On the other hand, deploying a Task queue (and its [message broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker)) require more time. You have to choose the right tools first then learn how to implement them in your PHP code. But this is the way to go in 2011.

Thank God, I don't do PHP but have played around with [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) (coupled with `RabbitMQ`) on *Python* projects ; I am sure you can find something similar in the PHP world.

Comment: Thanks, Stan! Is Message Queues invasive. Meaning, implementing message queues requires PHP code changes in the application?

Comment: _A priori_ it is not. **but** the parameter of the function delayed must be serializable and sometimes you may have some surprises because some object are not well handled.

Comment: yay. This is 2013 and still same rule is valid