# Running scheduled tasks in php

Tags: php, cron

I have a table, that consists of all the info to run a campaign. The info includes, the time interval to check the campaign (10 mins, 15 mins etc.) and other information to check whether it meets the specific requirement or not, to run the campaign.

At the moment, what I am planning to do is:

- Add my code in one php file
- In the code, go through all the rows of the table
- Check if it's the time to check the campaign or not (via the interval)
- If it's the time to check the campaign, then go through other details of the table and based on the set conditions, send an email or SMS.
- I am planning to run a cron job which goes through this php file, after every 10 minutes (As it's the shortest check interval)

I need suggestions, whether it's the proper solution or not OR if someone has any better and efficient solution?

Comment: It can be done thus. If there's a specific problem with your code, do not hesitate to ask. Bye!

Comment: I'd use a message queue between those steps. A single PHP file/thread doing everything is not scaling very well. Besides, your question is rather broad and many solutions will fit until it comes down to a specific problem.

Comment: @DanielW. Yes, I also thought of using RabbitMQ previously. But, later got lost in between. Where would you specifically recommend to use the queue?

Comment: You can use RabbitMQ to seperate portions semantically and distribute load. Like you have workers for sending mail/sms, workers for fetching campaing data, ...

Comment: @DanielW. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

That's a decent starting point...

> If it's the time to check the campaign...

Keep in mind that sometimes a cron process takes longer than expected, gets stuck or your system crashes in the middle. Ideally your process will keep track of a.) what it's doing, and b.) when it did it. And be able to fix problems like skipped or stuck processing.

It could be that you never want to send a message that late. Then again you may want to make sure all of the missed messages get sent. Your code should be able to handle this case automatically to some degree. Maybe automatically do anything that's should've been done in the last hour but wasn't and ignore anything older than that. For older stuff you'd have to manually run the script. Make sure your script has command line arguments that simplify you forcing it to run for prior time intervals and specific campaign IDs. This will make your life way easier after a disaster.

I suggest that you have some kind of reporting so you can keep track of your processing in real time. Pretty simple if you're writing state info to your database. Add on an end of processing timestamp and you can even see how long your cron jobs are running. If you don't want to use this state info in your cron job you can just write it to a log file instead of a database. And in that case (if needed) you would use a lock file to indicate when a cron job is running and prevent other cron jobs from starting at the same time. Regardless, it's good practice to write a log file so you have a record of what happened. Imagine if your cron job sent an email but crashed while attempting to write the state to the database. You'd at least have a log line to help you investigate later.

> I am planning to run a cron job which goes through this php file,
>   after every 10 minutes (As it's the shortest check interval)

So the speed of your script will vary with the amount of data, latency of external services (assuming your script talks directly to such services). I would start with a much longer cron job start interval - assuming that your client/use case allows for that. If you follow the suggestion above to have your script automatically handle skipped times this isn't a problem. The more stuff you're processing the more time your script will eventually need. So on day 1 it might only need 1 second. But on day 300 it might need 15 minutes? (At that point you could decide that you want to have multiple processes/threads running at the same time with each one focused on a single campaign or range of campaigns. Who knows...) But you'll know because you have reports/alerts/logs on the start/end processing times.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed description. I appreciate that. Do you also believe that I should use message queues?

Comment: I don't disagree with what @danielw said about that. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599664/difference-between-using-message-queue-vs-plain-cron-jobs-with-php